# Reference Request: Characterization of Contractability

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

On this [page](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Contractible_space#Equivalent_definitions_in_tabular_format) it is claimed that a non-empty topological space $X$, is contractable if and only if given any two $f,g:Y\rightarrow X$ (for any topological space $Y$) $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

I was looking for a reference which states this fact, both so I can quote it in a paper I am working on and to understand the details myself.  Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: This statement is not quite correct: you need to also assume that $X$ is nonempty.

Comment: Most people define topological spaces to have at-least one point (no?)  So that Top has the initial object *.

Comment: No, I have never seen anyone who defines topological spaces to have at least one point.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I didn't know this (I looked up on the great: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space).  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to change your wording to include nonempty spaces, you can ask that there is a single homotopy class of maps $Y \rightarrow X$. This is more in tune with the Yoneda philosophy. Namely, spaces and homotopy classes of maps form a category, and if $Hom(-,X)$ is always a singleton, then $Hom(-,X)$ is naturally isomorphic to $Hom(-,*)$, so $X$ is isomorphic to a point. And being contractible is equivalent to being homotopy equivalent to a point. I don't claim this is the right way a beginner should look at this, but its a nice example of this way of thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One might find such a thing as an exercise in an algebraic topology book. I'm doubtful that it would be stated as a separate, citable theorem, although I suppose one could comb through the textbook references given on that web page you linked. In lieu of that, here's a proof.

For the "if" direction, use the functions $f,g : X \to X$ where $f$ is the identity and $g$ is a constant.

For the "only if" direction, let $h : X \times [0,1] \to X$ be a homotopy from the identity map to a constant map $c_p : X \to \{p\} \subset X$. It follows that $h_f(x,t)=h(f(x),t)$ defines a homotopy from $f$ to the constant map $d_p : Y \to \{p\} \subset X$, and similarly with $h_g(x,t)=h(g(x),t)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are both homotopic to $d_p$, they are homotopic to each other.